# Postgres SQL to query array text[] in specific element

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

This is the data that I'm trying to query:
Table name: "test", column "data"

```
7;"{{Hello,50},{Wazaa,90}}"
8;"{{Hello,50},{"Dobar Den",15}}"
```

To query this data I'm using this SQL query:

```
SELECT *, pg_column_size(data) FROM test WHERE data[1][1] = 'Hello'
```

How I can search in all elements but in the first sub element and not in the second for example:

```
SELECT *, pg_column_size(data) FROM test WHERE data[][1] = 'Hello'
```

because if I search like this:

```
SELECT *, pg_column_size(data) FROM test WHERE data[1][1] = "Wazaa"
```

it won't return anything because I'm hardcoding to look at first sub element and I have to modify it like this:

```
SELECT *, pg_column_size(data) FROM test WHERE data[2][1] = 'Wazaa'
```

How to make it to check all parent elements and first sub element?

there is solution using "ANY" to query all elements but I don't want to touch second element in where statement because if I have numbers in first sub element it will query the second parameter which is also number.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE '90' = ANY (data);
```

Comment: As you are essentially storing key/value pairs, it would be **much** more efficient to use a `hstore` column for this.

Comment: I think it's better with hstore.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL's support for arrays is not particularly good. You can `unnest` a 1-dimensional array easy enough, but a n-dimensional array is completely flattened, rather than only the first dimension. Still, you can use this approach to find the desired set of records, but it is rather ugly:

```
SELECT test.*, pg_column_size(test.data) AS column_size
FROM test
JOIN (SELECT id, unnest(data) AS strings FROM test) AS id_strings USING (id)
WHERE id_strings.strings = 'Wazaa';
```

Alternatively, write [this function](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Unnest_multidimensional_array) to reduce a 2-dimensional array into records of 1-dimensional arrays and then you can basically use all of the SQL queries in your question.

Comment: Which database is better for arrays?

Comment: Most databases as we know them today are [relational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model). That makes them inherently ill-fitted for sequential data structures like arrays. In general, you will be advised to change your data model in such a way that you do not need arrays to begin with.

Comment: @Patrick: actually I think in the world of relational databases, Postgres' array support is extremely good - no other DBMS I know offers this kind of flexibility. As with any feature: you can always improve this. Whether or not an array is a good choice for a specific problem is a completely different topic though.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name PostgreSQL may provide _extremely better_ support than other DBMS'es, but that still does not make any RDBMS well-suited for _manipulating_ arrays.