# UPDATE Query takes very long PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to `UPDATE` several rows in the table `myTable` (335379 rows).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION costs_f(
someFloat float) RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN
UPDATE ways 
SET cost_time = CASE WHEN $1 = -1.0 THEN -1 ELSE anotherFloat * $1 END
FROM (SELECT w.gid AS id,
mc.name,
w.someCosts
FROM myTable mt
JOIN myClasses mc
ON mt.class_id = mc.class_id) AS tempTable
WHERE gid = id AND tempTable.name_name = $2;
END
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

This function is then called in another function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_costs_f(
someFloat float) RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE
someArr varchar[] := ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 
    'j', 'k', 'l',
    'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 
    'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'ul', 'v'];
i text;
BEGIN
FOREACH i IN ARRAY someArr LOOP
    PERFORM costs_f($1, i);
END LOOP;
END
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

Then I do

```
SELECT update_costs_f(10.0);
```

However, that takes very very long!
Is there a way to improve speed?

*Note: This code is abstracted. In the second function there are more `ForEach` loop. I have several arrays.

Comment: You obfuscated your code to an extent that it's no longer valid. You are passing a character string to `costs_f()` inside the loop, but the function expects a float value. The function also uses a variable `anotherfloat` that is not declared anywhere. And, unrelated but: comparing a float for equality can have many surprising results: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: It's still invalid - but the example given can be reduced to a single update statement and no function needed. So your abstraction is not helping.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name of course I can write it into one statement. But these function get called at different spots from different parts of the program. So I need them to be in two different functions. What I am interested in is, why the update takes so long when I execute it the way I execute the function.

Comment: Because you are doing a slow row-by-row update. A single statement updating many rows is always faster then many statements updating a single row. The only way to improve this, is to get rid of the slow, inefficient and non-scalable row-by-row processing

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah, thanks. Could you give me a hint what to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Get rid of tempTable.name_name = $2;

As @a_horse_with_no_name said, you should not be running multiple update statements.

I see you are calling `PERFORM costs_f($1, i)` multiple times for each letter in `someArr`. Instead of calling it multiple times, call it once and use the `in` operator, e.g. :

`AND tempTable.name_name in($2)`;

### 2. Split the Update into 2 Statements

You should split your update statement into two statements:

```
UPDATE ways 
SET cost_time = -1.0 FROM tempTable 
WHERE gid = id AND tempTable.name_name = $2 AND
$1 = -1.0 ;

UPDATE ways 
SET cost_time =anotherFloat * $1 FROM tempTable 
WHERE gid = id AND tempTable.name_name = $2 AND
NOT ($1 = -1.0) ;
```

Note: Simplified by only using tempTable  instead of the full nested subuery/alias

### 3. Move conditions into the nested Aliased From SubQuery

Right off the bat I can see you can move the condition `name_name = $2` directly into the `from aliased subquery`:

```
FROM (SELECT w.gid AS id,
mc.name,
w.someCosts
FROM myTable mt
JOIN myClasses mc
ON mt.class_id = mc.class_id 
WHERE name_name = $2 ) AS tempTable
WHERE gid = id;
```

### All Together

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_costs_f(
someFloat float) RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE
someArr varchar[] := ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',
    'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 
    'j', 'k', 'l',
    'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 
    'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'ul', 'v'];
i text;
BEGIN
PERFORM costs_f($1, someArr );
END
$$
language 'plpgsql';


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION costs_f(
someFloat float) RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN
UPDATE ways 
SET cost_time = -1.0
FROM (SELECT w.gid AS id,
mc.name,
w.someCosts
FROM myTable mt
JOIN myClasses mc
ON mt.class_id = mc.class_id
WHERE $1 = -1.0 AND gid = id AND tempTable.name_name = ANY($2);
) AS tempTable;    

UPDATE ways 
SET cost_time =anotherFloat * $1 
FROM (SELECT w.gid AS id,
mc.name,
w.someCosts
FROM myTable mt
JOIN myClasses mc
ON mt.class_id = mc.class_id
WHERE NOT($1 = -1.0) AND gid = id AND tempTable.name_name =ANY($2);
) AS tempTable;

END
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

### Finally

You could use an IF statement in order to not run both SQL update statements...

See: [PostgreSQL IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11299037/1688441)
Example:

```
IF ($1 = -1.0) THEN
   ...
ELSE 
  ...
END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks. Your are missing a function argument in `costs_f`. When calling it, (`PERFORM costs_f($1, someArr );` your passing `$1` and `someArr` but you are not defining it `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION costs_f(
someFloat float) RETURNS void AS` here.

Comment: @Stophface  Yeh... but have you tried the change to check the speed?

Comment: I am trying to implement. Its mocking around with the array. I changed `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION costs_f(
someFloat float someText text[]) RETURNS void AS` and `SELECT PERFORM costs_f($1, someArr::text[]);` but its saying 
`ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = text[]
LINE 10: WHERE $1 = -1.0 AND gid = id AND tempTable.name_name in ($2) HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.` And the fancy `^` in the Error Message is pointing to `IN`

Comment: @Stophface http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/09/string-array-input-parameter-in-postgresql/ ?  `ArrayText character varying[]` . Try also instead of IN, the ANY function. http://stackoverflow.com/q/30298031/1688441 ... `ANY(ArrayText)`

Comment: I tried that the first time. I changed to `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION costs_f( someFloat float someText  character varying[])` and the typecast as well `:: character varying[]`. Same error. Same results with `varchar[]`. I tried changing `IN` to `ANY` already. `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ANY"  text = text[] LINE 10: WHERE $1 = -1.0 ANY gid = id AND`

Comment: hmmmm the problem seems to be `WHERE $1 = -1.0 AND gid = id AND tempTable.name_name in ($2)` .... I think you may need to cast $2 as an array.

Comment: Yep, for sure. But how? Shouldnt that be one of `::text[] ::varchar[]` or `::character varying[]`?

Comment: It has to be consistent.. so either varying everywhere or varchar. Try varying and change the definition of the someArr  array as well. I think though you need to use the same in all places of both functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133461/discussion-between-stophface-and-maythesource-com).